# How to duplicate rows and increment column where incremented column value does not exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe like this:

```
id     alt    amount
6      b      30
6      a      30
3      d      56
3      a      40
1      c      35
1      b      10
1      a      20
```

which I would like to be turned into this:

```
id     alt    amount
6      d      56
6      c      35
6      b      30
6      a      30
5      d      56
5      c      35
5      b      26
5      a      33.33
4      d      56
4      c      35
4      b      22
4      a      36.66
3      d      56
3      c      35
3      b      18
3      a      40
2      c      35
2      b      14
2      a      30
1      c      35
1      b      10
1      a      20
```

For each missing id number N that is less than the maximum id number, all alt values for the largest id number smaller than N should be duplicated, with id number set to N for these duplicated rows. If the alt value is repeated for a larger id number, then the additional amount entries should increase by the difference divided by the difference between id values (number of steps.) If the alt value is not repeated, then the amount can simple be copied over for each additional id value.

For instance, a appears with id numbers 1, 3 and 6 and amounts 20, 40, 30 respectively. We need to add an instance of a with an id of 2. The amount in this will be 30, since it takes 2 steps to go from 1 to 3 and we are increasing by 20. Going from 3 to 6 there are 3 steps and we are decreasing by 10. -10/3 = -3.33, so we subtract 3.33 for each new instance of a.

I thought of doing some combination of duplicating, sorting, and forward filling? I'm unsure of the logic here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `pivot` + `reindex` then `interpolate`

```
yourdf=df.pivot(*df.columns).\
    reindex(range(df.id.min(),df.id.max()+1)).\
     interpolate(method='index').stack().reset_index()
yourdf
Out[51]: 
    id alt          0
0    1   a  20.000000
1    1   b  10.000000
2    1   c  35.000000
3    2   a  30.000000
4    2   b  14.000000
5    2   c  35.000000
6    3   a  40.000000
7    3   b  18.000000
8    3   c  35.000000
9    3   d  56.000000
10   4   a  36.666667
11   4   b  22.000000
12   4   c  35.000000
13   4   d  56.000000
14   5   a  33.333333
15   5   b  26.000000
16   5   c  35.000000
17   5   d  56.000000
18   6   a  30.000000
19   6   b  30.000000
20   6   c  35.000000
21   6   d  56.000000
```